# Single direction named pipes

Tags: c, multithreading, networking, pipe, named-pipes

A simple question. If I have 2 programs that needs to access 1 named pipe. If one uses open() function for reading on one end with `O_RDONLY` flag, would the other end be able to open the file as `O_WRONLY` and be able to write to it? Would the other program get the written data?

Comment: That's basically how named pipes work: one program writes, another reads. What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that.

if you use `O_RDWR` to open the pipe, it will not block.

if you use `O_RDONLY` to open the pipe, it will block until the writer opens the pipe, unless you used `O_NONBLOCK` to make sure to open the pipe successfully.

if you use `O_WRONLY` to open the pipe, it will block until the reader opens the pipe, but if you also use `O_NONBLOCK`, the `open()` will fail.